# Read Socket Line By Line but Memory Issue Occurs

Tags: c, linux, sockets, http, pointers

I implemented a HTTP client, which can receive the content by specifying the host name and port and display it line by line from socket. Below is my read one line function:

```
char* getLine(int fd)//fd is the socket number created before
{
    char c, pre;
    char* line = 0; 
    int size = 0;
    while(read(fd, &c, 1)!=0)
    {
        line = realloc(line, ++size);//read a new char so re-allocation
        line[size - 1] = c;

        if(pre == '\r' && c == '\n')//this is a new line
        {
            break;
        }
        pre = c;

    }
    if(line)
    {
        line = realloc(line, ++size);
        line[size - 1] = 0;//add a \0 at the end of line
    }
    return line;
}
```

Below is how I use this function in main function (assuming sockfd has been created and request has been sent to the server)

```
char* line;
while((line = getLine(sockfd)) != NULL)
{
    printf("%s", line);
    if(!strcmp(line, "\r\n"))//blank line
        printf("#####Now reading body.\n");

    free(line);
}
```

The problem is, when I try to get the content from some short pages such as google.com or yahoo.com, it works fine. However, if I want to try some long page, such as www.stanford.edu, it shows `realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000000c794b0 ***`.

It seems like my pointer has some undefined behaviors in that `getLine` function, but I really don't know where the problem is. Could anyone give me some hint? Thanks!

**Problem solved so source code has been deleted.

Comment: Using realloc and incrementing the size byte by byte is slow, leading to quadratic behaviour.  The normal trick is to double the size of the allocation each time you need more space (except for the 'add null' one).  You could also shrink an oversize allocation to fit the exact requirements.  That is not, directly, related to your problem/bug though.

Comment: The compiler should be warning you about 'may use variable `pre` uninitialized in this function'; initialize it to 0.  You should be checking that `realloc()` does not return a failure - null pointer.  Further, if it does, you leak memory because you've lost the previous non-null pointer.  Always use some variant on `void *new_space = realloc(old_space, new_size); if (new_space != 0) old_space = new_space;`.

Comment: `while(read(fd, &c, 1)!=0)` read can return -1 (which acts as `true`) ... just saying ...

Comment: @wildplasser, you beat me to the post by 8 minutes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The buffer you are allocating in createQuery() is too small.

The computed length does not account for HTTP_VERSION, and does not account for the terminating \0 byte. The result is memory corruption, and undefined behavior.